# Python - Turning a for-loop into a one-liner

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, scalar

I'm trying to create a matrix-multiplication-with-scalar function, without any libraries.
It has to include list comprehension:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]] # 2by2 matrix

scalar = 2 #positive int

product = []

for row in A:
    
    temp = []
    
    for element in row:
        temp.append(scalar * element)
    
    product.append(temp)

print(product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]] # 2by2 matrix

scalar = 2 #positive int

product = [[i*scalar for i in sublist] for sublist in A]

print(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can have some fun with lambdas and `map`:

```
product = [*map(lambda x: [*map(lambda y: y * scalar, x)], A)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31HBViE62lDHKFYn2ljHJDaWqzg5MSexCChsxMVVUJSfUppcAlKjlZtYoJGTmJuUkqhQYYXKr7RSqFTQUoDo1FGo0IzVUXDUjAXpz8wr0YCaovn/PwA)